# while loop not working for acessing sql records

Tags: php

I am passing a string to this file -txtname- (string separated by spaces) and saparate      each word and then pass it to the function `subtoken()` that should fetch the corresponding words from the database, having two attributes-rootwords and example,but `subtoken()` function executes only once and exits.

```
$counter=0; 

$string = $_REQUEST['txtname'];
$token = strtok($string, ' ');
while ($token != false)
{echo $counter;
  subtoken($token,$counter);

 $counter++;
 $token = strtok(' ');  

}


function subtoken($fname,$counter)
{
$row ="";
$result="";
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM hindi WHERE rootwords LIKE  \'%:'.$fname.':%\'' );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$temp=$row['rootwords'];
$token2 = strtok($temp, ':');
echo $token2 ;
while($token2!=false)
{

    echo $token2."<br/>" ;
    $token2=strtok(':');
}

}

}

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

The double usage of strtok will prevent the "main" loop to properly process all tokens from the original `$string`. You simply can't have more than one "open" `strtok` use at the same time.

Original suspect was your query, that it just doesn't select anything. Try printing the SQL statement, then executing that statement directly (e.g. via phpmyadmin)

```
// insert this line:
echo(
    'SELECT * FROM hindi '.
        'WHERE rootwords LIKE  \'%:'.$fname.':%\'');
// just before the actual query execution
$result = mysql_query(
    'SELECT * FROM hindi '.
        'WHERE rootwords LIKE  \'%:'.$fname.':%\'' );
```

From my experience, echo'ing as much data as possible early on while debugging is one of the best tools to easily spot errors.

Comment: 2nded. Output from phpmyadmin should be able to tell you what kind of dataset you're dealing with in the first place.

Comment: no .. this query runs well .. but only first time den exits.. i think because of second loop . .. when $token2 becomes false .. den it exits..

Comment: i will give u an example .. check it out..                             here $fname="ram" theni get $row=$result; $row[rootwords]=  :ram:sham:jam:naam:  then the second loop is used for splitting it as ram ,sham , jam,nam.. and this should be happen for only one time ..as $token2 print the value as ram  ,sham,nam and jam .. and then exits..

Comment: So actually the tokenizer doesn't tokenize properly? You should've put that in the question, it would really have helped recognizing where the problem may lie... but now I don't really understand what the exact problem is, could you reformulate it - maybe not here in the comments but by editing the original question!

Comment: Ah I think I see now. It's the call to strtok in two locations; once in your "main loop", once in subtoken. Each call of strtok with the string argument will start the tokenizing anew, doesn't matter if that's inside a method or not (it keeps state internally somewhere). you need to rewrite that.

Answer (score 0):

See also: http://nl2.php.net/mysql_fetch_array
mysql_fetch_array needs a second parameter to work correctly.

Replace mysql_fetch_array with mysql_fetch_row. Or mysql_fetch_assoc if you want to reference to the columns by name.

Comment: Not true. `mysql_fetch_array`, just as `mysql_fetch_row`, delivers one row from the database at a time; just in a different format: the one delivers them string-indexed (_array), while the other (_row) indexed by column number.

Comment: even after edit, still not true. the second parameter in mysql_fetch_array is optional

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some error/warning? Is error_reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors to "On"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that strtok() has only one pointer. So, when you ended with it in function, you need to reinitialise `$token = strtok($string, ' ');`? dut I am not sure. I think it would be better if you used [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.